# Error when trying to display a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, this, android-context

Had this problem when trying to display a Dialog with a time picker where an exception is thrown if I initialize the `TimePickerDialog` with the context returned from `getBaseContext()` as opposed to using a `this` reference to the current activity.
So this code is fine:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id )
{
   return new TimePickerDialog( this , mTimeSetListener, hr, min, false);
}
```

but this code throws an exception

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id )
{
   return new TimePickerDialog( getBaseContext(), mTimeSetListener, hr, min, false);
}
```

If I want to display a Toast then I would use

```
    Toast.makeText( getBaseContext() , ...
```

and this also works.

My question is I would have thought the context I want the Dialog to display in would be the `baseContext` so why does a Toast work using this but a Dialog needs a reference to "this" ,  i.e.,  the current activity as I would have thought they are both very similar in how they work?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `getBaseContext()` unless you know what you are doing and have a very specific and concrete reason for using it.

You do not need it for a `Toast`, and you do not need it for a `Dialog`. Whatever `Activity` you are using for those is a perfectly good `Context` for creating `Toasts` and `Dialogs`, so just use `this`.